# Visual studio 2012 publish database project to sql instance on a separate server fails when firewall is turned on

Tags: database, visual-studio, publish, firewall

Computer A has visual studio 2012 with a sql database project. 
Computer B has windows server 2008 r2 and sql server 2008 r2.
I am trying to publish the database project from visual studio to the sql instance.
With the windows firewall turned off on Computer B, everything works; with the firewall on it fails. The error message is "The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that sql server is configured to allow remote connections (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to Sql Server".

I have tried creating rules for incoming ports for udp and tcp for both 1433 and 1434. I have also added the program sqlservr.exe. Each exception/rule was applied to domain. private, and public. I don't know what else I need to do to allow visual studio to publish the database to the sql instance with the firewall on.

Thank you for any help!